# Unable to switch page DisplayMode in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, fakedb

I am trying to test one of the properties which checks for the `PageMode.IsExperienceEditor`. Reduced implementation of my property is given below:

```
public ContentResult DataSourceNotConfiguredResult
{
    get
    {
        if(Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
        {
            //Some Code
        }
        //Some other code

        return Content("Some Value");
    }
}
```

In my unit test, I am trying to change the display mode using the `SetDisplayMode` function. Here is my sample implementation for the test:

```
StringDictionary _stringDictionary;
FakeSiteContext _fakeSite;

[TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _stringDictionary = new StringDictionary();
            _stringDictionary.Add("name", "website");
            _stringDictionary.Add("database", "master");

            _fakeSite = new FakeSiteContext(_stringDictionary);
        }

[TestMethod]
        public void HiddenRenderingResult_ReturnsHtmlString_WhenCalledInExperienceEditor()
        {
            var fakeDb = new Db("master");
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            DbItem fakeRenderingItem = new DbItem("StaticDataSourceItem", new Sitecore.Data.ID(guid));
            fakeDb.Add(fakeRenderingItem);            

            _fakeSite.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.Edit, DisplayModeDuration.Remember);

            using (new SiteContextSwitcher(_fakeSite))
            using (RenderingContext.EnterContext(new Rendering(), fakeDb.GetItem(new Sitecore.Data.ID(guid))))
            {
                //Do Something
            }
        }
```

However, even after `SetDisplayMode` call, I still see the DisplayMode set as normal. Here is my screenshot from the debug session:

[image]

I referred to [this article](https://jockstothecore.com/how-to-test-automation/) as well which basically does the same thing.

I am confused by what I am missing. I would appreciate any pointers that nudge me in the correct direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/sshushliapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/issues/207) and needs to be fixed in FakeDb. But the good news is that you may hotfix it following the [article](https://jockstothecore.com/how-to-test-automation/) instructions carefully:

1. add `shell` site registration to your config:

   ```
   <sites>
       <site name="shell" domain="sitecore"></site>
   </sites>
   ```
2. define class parameters in the following way (remove `name`, add `masterDatabase`):

   ```
   _stringDictionary.Add("database", "master");
   _stringDictionary.Add("enableWebEdit", "true");
   _stringDictionary.Add("masterDatabase", "master");
   ```

Now the test does not fail:

```
Assert.True(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing); // pass
```

Comment: Thanks @Serhii ! That helped!